# Php aceess array string key but doesn't get resultt

Tags: php, parameters

just a quick test on a local machine I have a php piece of code that picks up some config parameters

```
$config["dbname"] = "whatawonderfulwall";
$config["dbhost"] = "localhost";
$config["dbuser"] = "WWWDBUSER";
$config["dbpwd"] = "yys678.,)3Yyh3";
$config["dbcharset"] = "utf8";
```

I know is ugly and you shouldn't to it this way all I really have to do is test a software locally for different behabvours with a list of different local databases.

Whnever I try to access one of these parameters it gives me a

For example

```
$db = $config["dbname"];
```

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WWWServer/api.php on line 94

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: The code you supplied is [valid](https://3v4l.org/SPLtX), so the problem is elsewhere. Can you post line 94

Comment: You're probably doing that inside a function, and as such your `$config` is not in scope. You need to pass it in as an argument (or in case of class, add to property). What you have above isn't ugly per se, it's just an array with config. What you do with it down the line may be ugly though. Wouldn't know without seeing more code.

Comment: dear @ChrisHaas the last line of code in the message is line 94

Comment: As noted, we need to see the code around it to debug further. However, somehow the variable `$config` is being created as an int, so you just need to walk this code back further. This is a case where a good IDE would probably help you spot things like this.